# Unity 3d: Script exist in multiple locations

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a free FPS kit from [OneManArmy](http://armedunity.com/files/file/13-fps-kit-2/). And what I did is I imported the locomotion prefab of the soldier in the UNITY Bootcamp demo Project into this fps kit project.

Then suddenly, these 2 errors appeared:

**Scripts named 'Grenade.js' exist in multiple locations (Assets/Scripts/weapons/Grenade.js). Please rename one of the scripts to a unique name.**

**Scripts named 'Grenade.js' exist in multiple locations (Assets/Resources/OldScripts/WeaponScripts/Grenade.js). Please rename one of the scripts to a unique name.**

I tried to delete, or rename each one but more errors appeared.

So what should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right clic > refresh/reimport/reimport all in the project window after deleting Assets/Resources/OldScripts/WeaponScripts/Grenade.js ?